# How to refer a custom column in the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns First Name and Last Name and an ID which is the PK. My WHERE condition will be a search operation upon the FullName and not separately.

SELECT:

```
select ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName 
from tbl_Employee
```

What I want:

```
select ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName 
from tbl_Employee 
where FullName like ''%' + @searchText + '%''
```

But when I try to use the alias FullName, it doesn't allow me to do so. How do I go about with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure the query a couple of different ways.  One, include the concatenataion in the `where` clause:

```
select
    e.ID,
    e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName as FullName 
from tbl_Employee as e
where e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName like '%' + @searchText + '%';
```

Two, use a sub-select as @lajja has shown.

Three, set it out as a non-recursive CTE.  I find this form easiest to read and understand:

```
;with EmployeeFullName as
(
    select
        e.ID,
        e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName as FullName
    from tbl_Employee as e
)
select
    f.ID,
    f.FullName
from EmployeeFullName as f
where f.FullName like '%' + @searchText + '%';
```

Note that by a) using a leading wildcard and b) concatenating columns you will stop the optimizer from using any indexes on `FirstName` or `LastName`.

Comment: Like the concatenation, can I also include case statements in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @Salihdeen yes you can.

Comment: Is the semi-colon at the start necessary?

Comment: @Salihdeen, if the previous statement finished with a semicolon, no. I'm now in the habit of adding one anyway since it can do no harm.

Comment: That clarifies it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below answer:

```
select Employee.* from (Select ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName  from tbl_Employee ) as Employee 
where Employee.FullName like ''%' + @searchText + '%''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
select ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName 
from tbl_Employee 
where (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) like '''%' + @searchText + '%'''
```